# find git files that are committed but not pushed

Tags: git

The normal git workflow is

- Edit files
- git add
- git commit
- git push

I am trying to find a command that tells me if there is anything that has been committed but not pushed.
I have tried

```
git diff --stat --cached master
```

But this gives the same result before and after a push, but I thought that a push would removed the changed files from that staging area

Please can someone tell me the correct command for this.

Comment: `git status` will show if your local branch has diverged from the remote.

Comment: Doh!! Thanks for the pointer

Comment: How do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: Hang on, I just realised an actual answer could be useful ... and then, if the answer is helpful, there should be a tick/check mark beside it you can select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've committed but not yet pushed, your local branch is ahead of (or has diverged from) it's upstream branch (usually `origin/BRANCHNAME`).

In general, you can see this with

```
git status
```

which will say something like

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

If you want to see specifically what files changed, something like

```
git diff --stat origin/master..HEAD
```

will show you (the generalized version, if you want a script to cope with any branch and remote, is harder).

Comment: `git remote` lists all remotes which is certainly not what you want here (you need the remote for the current branch). Probably the simplest way is `git diff --stat @{u}..@` — i.e. from the upstream to `HEAD`.

Comment: ugh, you're right - I'd forgotten how painful it is to get that nicely

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check with the previous head if it is not yet pushed, or if you want to check against the previously pushed commit from remote. This command should do the trick for you.

```
git diff --stat HEAD HEAD~1
```

**Downside:** It's not exactly all non-pushed commits but only the previous one. Maybe somebody finds this useful.